# How to target and iterate through just one specific column (by column name) in Google sheets / apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

So I have an OnEdit function that detects when data is copy and pasted into the spreadsheet and then where ever a color value is found, that cells background colour becomes that color.

However, currently it is iterating through every cell in the spreadsheet which is very slow when data is copied and pasted. I only want it to iterate through and detect copy and pasted changes within the "CategoryColor" column of my spreadsheet.

This is what I have so far, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  
    var firstRow = e.range.getLastRow() - e.range.getHeight() + 1;
    var firstColumn = e.range.getLastColumn() - e.range.getWidth() + 1;
    var values = e.range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < e.range.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < e.range.getWidth(); j++) {
            try {
                // changes background colour of cell
                e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(firstRow + i, firstColumn + j).setBackground(values[i][j]);
               
            } catch (e) {
              Logger.log(e);
            }
        }
    }
  
  // sets data validation
  setDataValidation(createColorList());
  getColumnData(activeSpreadsheet);
  getFullColumn(columnIndex, startIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to implement an `if` statement that assesses the edited column before executing the rest of the script.

### Sample using the method [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the correct column:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var sheet=e.source.getActiveSheet();
 var headers=sheet.getRange(1,1,1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues; //assuming the headers are in row 1, otherwise change it accordingly
var column=headers[0].indexOf("CategoryColor")+1; //finds the column with the header "CategoryColor" 
 if(e.range.getColumn()==column){
// YOUR SCRIPT
    var firstRow = e.range.getLastRow() - e.range.getHeight() + 1;
    var firstColumn = e.range.getLastColumn() - e.range.getWidth() + 1;
    var values = e.range.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < e.range.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < e.range.getWidth(); j++) {
            try {
                // changes background colour of cell
                e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(firstRow + i, firstColumn + j).setBackground(values[i][j]);

            } catch (e) {
              Logger.log(e);
            }
        }
    }

  // sets data validation
  setDataValidation(createColorList());
  getColumnData(activeSpreadsheet);
  getFullColumn(columnIndex, startIndex);
  }
}
```

> > NOTE:

- `e.range` will  be a single cell and will consequently contain only one value.
- Thus, evaluate if 
  `var values = e.range.getValues();`
  and 
  `e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(firstRow + i, firstColumn + j).setBackground(values[i][j]);`
  makes sense.
- If you only want to change the background color of the cell that was edited, maybe you can just use
  `var value = e.range.getValue();`
  and 
  `e.range.setBackground(value);`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the only issue is that the user is able to change the order of the columns? the column may not always be the 5th column? is it possible to target by column name??? again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, this is possible if you know in which row the column header is located. I will update my code with a sample.